# I need help building a date timer that relates between objects

Tags: lightning, formula, workflow, formula-field, date

This was my guidance for this task:

**Problem:**

We have Production records and Requirement (RFI) records.
We need to be able to track the 90 Days from an initial RFI Date regardless of the number of RFIs as they all correspond to that 1st Response Date.

**Solution:**
3-Steps is what I envision for this:
Create an (1) Date Field followed by a (2) 90 day counter and (3) reflect that counter onto each related Requirement record.

- 90 Days is only 1 per Production Order
- This will be a manual process for now
- Counter (2) should stop at 0 Days
- Note: I would like to limit fields as much as possible, but this may require a Date (Start) field and a Date (End) field to measure.  If there is absolutely no other way than please hide this field from the record to save space as it is unimportant and redundant.

Let me know how you would approach solving this-thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind your preference for limiting fields, I think I would try something like this:

**Date Field (Start Date):**

Create a Date field on the Production record named '*Initial RFI Date*'. This will capture the date of the first RFI. As per your guidance, it seems this will be a manual process for now.

**Formula Field (End Date):**

Instead of creating a separate end date, use a formula field named *90 Days Deadline* that calculates Initial RFI Date + 90. This field won't need to be displayed on the record page but will be used internally to calculate the counter.

**90-Day Counter:**

Create another formula field named Days Remaining. This will calculate the difference between the current date and the 90 Days Deadline. The formula will look something like this:

IF(
(90 Days Deadline - TODAY()) >= 0,
(90 Days Deadline - TODAY()),
0
)

The idea is that the formula checks if there are days remaining until the deadline. If the difference is positive, it displays the number of days left. If not, it displays 0.

**Reflect Counter on Each Requirement (RFI) Record:**

On the RFI object, create a formula field that pulls the Days Remaining value from the related Production record. This way, each RFI related to a Production will show the days remaining from the initial RFI date.

Not sure if I'm on the right track here. Let me know.

Comment: This was perfect Paulo, thank you!

Comment: That's great to hear Jesse!